# Take information from point along coast and make it inland

Tags: arcgis-pro, mapping, extract, erosion, value-extraction

I'm trying to create a map in ArcGIS Pro using the National Coastal Erosion Risk Mapping Dataset. The dataset shows the likely amount of erosion (metres) at each point along today's UK coastline. I'm trying to take the erosion value at each point and extract it inland that many metres. Ie, make a map of the new coastline in 10, 20, 100 years using the current national coastal erosion maps.

The issue I have is how to extract that information for thousands (if not more) of datapoints along the east coast of England. More to the point, how do I create new points that go INLAND - because inland is not always just 'east' for each point... I'm struggling to think how to do it and whether it can be done at all.

Comment: I think this is getting close votes because you said "ArcGIS Pro *or* QGIS". If you stick to one tool then its less likely to get closed. Hit the edit button and remove one! A link to the data would help too, and maybe some maps. Is it this? https://environment.data.gov.uk/portalstg/home/item.html?id=f43303a72b4e455ab0d7449ca65b4bb3

Comment: To figure out "inland" you need a geometry for the land, in other words a polygon border for your whole region, ie England. Then you can generate buffers that are `_erosion_distance_` around your coast and then crop or test to the polygon border which you know to be inland...

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your comments, that's really appreciated. I've changed the edit to include just one type of GIS system. You're right about the dataset, that's exactly it. I'm trying to use that to create a map showing the coastline at 10 years, 50 years and 100 years (or whatever each time frame is meant to show). I'm probably showing my inexperience here, but what do you mean by cropping or testing polygon borders that I know to be inland... Thank you so much again for your help - it is seriously appreciated

Comment: Can you edit your Q and tell us a bit more about the data? Which columns describe the amount of erosion? What I'm saying about cropping is that you also need a complete UK or ENG coast polygon as well as the erosion data lines. Then you buffer the lines by some distance to create "sausage-shaped" polygons, and then subtract those from your UK polygon.

Comment: @Spacedman, Just been experimenting with the idea of erasing the coast with the sausage-buffer. I had thought of that approach too. The result is a smoothed coastline which looks artificial. It does not take into account the direction of erosion induced by differences in geology (e.g. one would expect erosion to exploit a fault for example). I wonder if the buffer approach (which is easy to do) is the worst case scenario? Everything erodes in all directions. Interesting!

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the data and attribute table?

Comment: The data that I linked to is 12706 short *lines* and not points, so my idea would be to buffer each line by the amount of erosion expected for it (which might be in the attributes? I can't find info on those) and subtract *that* from the coastline polygon.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an England polygon layer with the erosion layer. My coastline here doesn't match exactly to the erosion data because its probably a bit generalised - get the best you can from available sources:

[image]

Create a buffer round the line segments based on how much erosion each line segment expects. In this case I've used one of the attributes which has a few zeroes and some other non-zero values. Use flat-ended buffers instead of the default round ones:

[image]

Then difference the England polygon with all these buffers to get:

[image]

There's a few weird spikes where the line segments end, but I reckon those can be removed with a bit of tweaking. But this seems like the basic algorithm for doing what you want, eroding different distances along the coast, driven by data in the line shapefile.